# SharePoint 2010 Configuration Failed : Failed to Create Configuration DB

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation, administration, central-administration

- While Configuration of SharePoint Configuration Wizard , Unexpectedly
  I came across below exception
- I had opened the log file and I see the below error information.Can any one help me ion knowing for what reason I had encountered the issue

  1. Resource retrieved id PostSetupConfigurationFailedEventLog is Configuration of SharePoint Products failed.  Configuration must be performed in order for this product to operate properly.  To diagnose the problem, review the extended error information located at {0}, fix the problem, and run this configuration wizard again. ##
  2. Configuration of SharePoint Products failed.  Configuration must be performed in order for this product to operate properly.  To diagnose the problem, review the extended error information located at C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\LOGS\PSCDiagnostics_1_10_2017_8_41_44_811_767225631.log, fix the problem, and run this configuration wizard again. ##
  3. Sending a task driver stop event: TaskDriverEventArgs.EventCriticalityType error, TaskDriverEventArgs.EventType.stop, Configuration of SharePoint Products failed.  Configuration must be performed before you use SharePoint Products.  For further details, see the diagnostic log located at C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\LOGS\PSCDiagnostics_1_10_2017_8_41_44_811_767225631.log and the application event log. ##
  4. Received a TaskDriverEventHandler: TaskDriverEventArgs.EventCriticalityType error, TaskDriverEventArgs.EventType stop, message Configuration of SharePoint Products failed.  Configuration must be performed before you use SharePoint Products.  For further details, see the diagnostic log located at C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\LOGS\PSCDiagnostics_1_10_2017_8_41_44_811_767225631.log and the application event log. ##
  5. Received a TaskDriverEventHandler: TaskDriverEventArgs.EventCriticalityType: error, TaskDriverEventArgs.EventMessageType: notapplicable, TaskDriverEventArgs.EventType stop, message: Configuration of SharePoint Products failed.  Configuration must be performed before you use SharePoint Products.  For further details, see the diagnostic log located at C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\LOGS\PSCDiagnostics_1_10_2017_8_41_44_811_767225631.log and the application event log. ##

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [following post on the MSDN](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/a7949c99-468b-44c7-b69c-9e48687c441e/failed-to-create-configuration-database?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious) it is known issue.

This is a known issue and a KB article is available [here .](http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=974405)

Solution: Download and install Windows Identity Foundation from the [download page here](http://wordpress.redirectingat.com/?id=725X1342&site=iconraja.wordpress.com&xs=1&isjs=1&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.microsoft.com%2Fdownload%2Fen%2Fdetails.aspx%3Fdisplaylang%3Den%26id%3D17331&xguid=85d0d50dccfb2e7f496b75f87d2476fb&xuuid=2098e762c4beac61d46eaa34eaa2d1f9&xsessid=ea8d59ea1b3e7232c6822f1e7aca91e1&xcreo=0&xed=0&sref=https%3A%2F%2Ficonraja.wordpress.com%2F2011%2F09%2F02%2Fsharepoint-2010-failed-to-create-configuration-database-error%2F&pref=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.bing.com%2F&xtz=300)

Comment: Facing error as "cannot start service spusercodev4 on computer sharepoint 2010" during sharepoint installation configuration wizard